# Textbox value should change when selecting the entire entered value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have two textbox if the first textbox reaches maxlength it auto-focuses to 2nd textbox.
Now issue is after entering maxlength again I select whole value which is entered in 1st textbox and try to edit different value but it moves to 2nd textbox.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
        <script>
        function branchAutoTab(){

            current = document.getElementById('primaryFilterBranchTextBox1');

            next = document.getElementById('primaryFilterBranchTextBox2');

            if (current.getAttribute&&current.value.length==current.getAttribute("maxlength")){

                next.focus();
            }
        }
        </script>

        <input id="primaryFilterBranchTextBox1" type="text" maxlength="3" class="controlFormatExtraSmall" onkeypress="javascript:if (event.keyCode!=8)branchAutoTab();" >
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Producer&nbsp;
        <input id="primaryFilterBranchTextBox2" type="text" maxlength="6" class="controlFormatExtraSmall"/> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Prakash K Any suggestion

Comment: Here is one: [Moving a focus when the input text field reaches a max length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959398/moving-a-focus-when-the-input-text-field-reaches-a-max-length) also read [this opinion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1959579/468763) in the same question.

Answer (score 0):

use onkeydown instead of onkeypress in the code snips:

```
<input id="primaryFilterBranchTextBox1" type="text" maxlength="3" class="controlFormatExtraSmall" onkeypress="javascript:if (event.keyCode!=8)branchAutoTab();" > &nbsp;&nbsp;Producer&nbsp;
          <input id="primaryFilterBranchTextBox2" type="text" maxlength="6" class="controlFormatExtraSmall"/>
```

Use this:

```
<input id="primaryFilterBranchTextBox1" type="text" maxlength="3" class="controlFormatExtraSmall" onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode!=8)branchAutoTab();" > &nbsp;&nbsp;Producer&nbsp;
          <input id="primaryFilterBranchTextBox2" type="text" maxlength="6" class="controlFormatExtraSmall"/>
```

modify if logic as below:

if (current.getAttribute&&current.value.length>current.getAttribute("maxlength")){
                 current.value=current.value.substr(0,current.value.length);
                next.focus();
            }

check if this helps

Comment: It is not working after reaches maxlength again it moves to 2nd textbox pls help me to find the fix

Comment: hi please check now...the if logic change will check if that the characters entered should exceed and not be equal to the max length then only will the focus change

Comment: @Vinnet Verma If I change that if condition auto tab function is not working

Comment: auto tab will work as soon as you type one extra character...u might need to right the extra logic to transfer the extra character to the next value...also try to google Javascript for autotab at maxlength. this might give you some already available js file for ur need...\

Comment: Varma My old script works for auto tab when it reaches it is autotab to next textbox

Comment: it works i can understand, but it is creating an issue and needs to be changed accordingly...i had tried this once and it worked for me..you can try the same

Comment: Who is this user2143039...??