# Focus and enable next input once reaching maxlength value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I enable and focus next input when maxlength is reached?

```html
<fieldset class="contenedor-fecha">
  <div class="contenedor-fecha-interior">
    <div class="contenedor-input-fecha"><input maxlength="1" class="input-fecha" placeholder="D" type="text"></div>
    <div class="contenedor-input-fecha elemento1"><input maxlength="1" class="input-fecha" placeholder="D" type="text" disabled></div>

    <div class="contenedor-input-fecha"><input class="input-fecha" maxlength="1" placeholder="M" type="text" disabled></div>
    <div class="contenedor-input-fecha elemento2"><input class="input-fecha" maxlength="1" placeholder="M" type="text" disabled></div>

    <div class="contenedor-input-fecha"><input class="input-fecha" maxlength="1" placeholder="Y" type="text" disabled></div>
    <div class="contenedor-input-fecha"><input class="input-fecha" maxlength="1" placeholder="Y" type="text" disabled></div>
    <div class="contenedor-input-fecha"><input class="input-fecha" maxlength="1" placeholder="Y" type="text" disabled></div>
    <div class="contenedor-input-fecha"><input class="input-fecha" maxlength="1" placeholder="Y" type="text" disabled></div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Focus next input once reaching maxlength value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595652/focus-next-input-once-reaching-maxlength-value)

Comment: I already tried that one but I dont know how to make it work with my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can compare the length of the value in the field to the `maxlength` property in the `input` event handler. From there you can enable and `focus()` on the next `input`. Try this:

```js
let $inputs = $('.contenedor-fecha-interior input').on('input', e => {
  let $input = $(e.target);
  let index = $inputs.index($input);
  
  if ($input.val().length >= $input.prop('maxlength')) {
    $inputs.eq(index + 1).prop('disabled', false).focus();
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="contenedor-fecha">
  <div class="contenedor-fecha-interior">
    <div class="contenedor-input-fecha"><input maxlength="1" class="input-fecha" placeholder="D" type="text"></div>
    <div class="contenedor-input-fecha elemento1"><input maxlength="1" class="input-fecha" placeholder="D" type="text" disabled></div>

    <div class="contenedor-input-fecha"><input class="input-fecha" maxlength="1" placeholder="M" type="text" disabled></div>
    <div class="contenedor-input-fecha elemento2"><input class="input-fecha" maxlength="1" placeholder="M" type="text" disabled></div>

    <div class="contenedor-input-fecha"><input class="input-fecha" maxlength="1" placeholder="Y" type="text" disabled></div>
    <div class="contenedor-input-fecha"><input class="input-fecha" maxlength="1" placeholder="Y" type="text" disabled></div>
    <div class="contenedor-input-fecha"><input class="input-fecha" maxlength="1" placeholder="Y" type="text" disabled></div>
    <div class="contenedor-input-fecha"><input class="input-fecha" maxlength="1" placeholder="Y" type="text" disabled></div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```