# Focusing next text field on condition satisfaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to learn jquery. I have two text fields. When the length of the first field becomes 3 i need the cursor to move to the next text box. How can i accomplish it? Please help me to find the answer

```
<input id="phone_field1" maxlength="3" name="phone_1" type="text">
<input id="phone_field2" maxlength="3" name="phone_1" type="text">
```

My code is given here. Please help me.

Comment: You've defined maxlength = 3 but wanted in 5 ????? A little bit unclear what you're trying to do her....

Comment: I am extremely sorry. It was 3 and it was a mistake. Hope its clear

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving a focus when the input text field reaches a max length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959398/moving-a-focus-when-the-input-text-field-reaches-a-max-length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like below:

```
$('#phone_field1').on('input',function(){//or keyup,you can use input rather id
  if($(this).val().length == $(this).prop('maxlength')){
   $(this).next().focus();
  }
});
```

Add missing bracket.