# change focus between several <p:inputtext> components in primefaces 3.5

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, focus

I have several  components in my page which I placed side by side, and each one has a max size of 2 digits. What I want is when 2 digits are typed in the first field, the cursor moves to the next one, and so on until the end.
Any hints please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [ask] and act accordingly. Especially the part about mcve. Also check the [jsf info tab](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) on this

Comment: And how would you do this if it were plain html/javascript? Please try the same.... you might be surprised...

Comment: This is not really related to PrimeFaces but more to Javascript. You could assign some id to your input and try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/1959404/2118909

Comment: Seems I figured out a solution with javascript, I'm going to try it, thanks for your hints.