# jQuery automatically move to next input with max reach value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to do move to the next input with last value. For example I want to enter credit card number and each number have max 4 digit capacity if digit is more then 4 then it'll automatically move to the next input with last added value.

For example I want to add 12345 so here 1234 will add in first input and 5 will automatically move to the next input.

```
1234 5
```

I have tried using following way , automatically move to next filed is work but not move last value.

```
$("#card3").bind("keypress", function (e) {
        var error = [];         
        var card3 =$("#card3").val();
        
        if ( card3.length > 3  ) {
                error.push('<p>Allow digits only(0 - 4).</p>');
                if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {              
                  $('#card4').focus();
                }
        }
```

I am going to add 12345 so 5 automatically move to the next input.

Comment: Whats the problem or question?

Comment: you can read the keycode and translate it to the number https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/ (subtract 48)

Comment: @ikiK, I want if any one type number like 12345 then 5 number will automatically move to the next field, currently only focus is working but value is not move to the next field

Comment: [Many more dupes](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+move+focus+max+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: [I like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40221557/295783)

Comment: @mplungjan, this is not duplicate question, read my question, I want to move the last input value also to the next

Comment: So you want to PASTE 12345 and have the 5 in the next field?

Comment: @mplungjan, Not paste when i enter 12345 then 5 will automatically move to the next

Comment: In the [dupe I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40221557/295783) you cannot enter 1 2 3 4 5 one at a time WITHOUT the 5 automatically going to the next field

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the dupe https://stackoverflow.com/a/40221557/295783 to handle paste

If you do not NEED to handle paste, then the dupe will work for you since you cannot enter the numbers without the number after the max going to the next field

Test the below by pasting in 16 digits in the first field OR type one digit at a time

```js
$("[data-max]").eq(0).on("input", function() {
  const val = this.value;
  if (val.length === 16) {
    const re = new RegExp(`.{${4}}`, "g")
    const chunks = val.match(re)
    chunks.forEach((chunk, i) => $("[data-max]").eq(i).val(chunk))
  }
})
$("[data-max]").on("input", function() {
  if (this.value.length >= this.dataset.max) {
    if (this.nextElementSibling) this.nextElementSibling.focus();
  }
})
$("[data-max]").last().on("input", function() {
  this.value = this.value.slice(0, 4)
})
```

```css
[data-max] {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-max="4" />
<input type="text" data-max="4" />
<input type="text" data-max="4" />
<input type="text" data-max="4" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is where the problem is

```
if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {              
                  $('#card4').focus();
                }
```

`this.maxLength` returns undefined therefore the block is never run.
Try

```
if (this.value.length == 4) {              
                  $('#card4').focus();
                }
```

You might want to add and retrieve maxLength value from input attribute

```
<input data-max-length="4" />

if (this.value.length == $(this).data('max-length')) {              
                  $('#card4').focus();
                }
```